# Can't save model during callback after_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have two models: Category and Subcategory, related like this:

```
class Category
  has_many :subcategories
  has_many :groups
end

class Subcategory
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :groups
end
```

Subcategory groups must be inherited from category.

I did it like this:

```
class Category
  has_many :subcategories
  has_many :groups
  after_save :pass_to_subcategories

  private
  def pass_to_subcategories
    subcategories.map do |sc| 
      sc.groups = groups
    end
  end

end
```

But during callback groups are empty. Apparently, i'm doing it wrong.
How i can do it correctly? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can just tell subcategories to look it up in the category:

```
class Subcategory
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :groups, through: :category
end
```

As for your code, I think you just need to call save on subcategory:

```
def pass_to_subcategories
  subcategories.map do |sc| 
   sc.groups = groups
   sc.save
  end
end
```